# XMPP GCM Python server not responding

Tags: android, python, sockets, google-cloud-messaging

I'm implementing GCM for Android based on the Android sample code:
https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/#git%2Fgcm-client%2FGcmClient%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fandroid%2Fgcm%2Fdemo%2Fapp

and the server sample code: 
https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html 
at the bottom of the page under Python sample.

After substituting my API key and sender ID, it worked for sometime at my office, and then stopped working (there's no exchange of messages, the server only sends out a "Bad registration" message and keeps waiting), then back to normal the next day. Now it stops working again.

I then tried the server code again at home, it's even worse:

```
Invalid debugflag given: socket
DEBUG:
DEBUG: Debug created for build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/xmpp/client.py
DEBUG:  flags defined: socket
DEBUG:
```

with not even a "Bad registration" message.

I suspect mostly the problem would be with the server, but I don't know if it's blocked by the network administrator (it shouldn't be). I've examined the possible registration problems, and it seems the registration id only gets messed up when there's an update. Any ideas what's happening here? TIA.

Comment: You sever side may cause problem, you can follow this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-server-to-send-push-notifications-with-gcm-to-android-devices-using-python to get some ideas.

Comment: Thanks! But I need to run an XMPP server. And my code just worked at my home...I really do not understand why the same code would work sometimes and not other times both at my home and office.

Comment: Maybe something has been blocked on your office side for security.

Comment: Well, I asked our network administrator and it doesn't seem that anything is blocked.